# Many people died but some got out alive

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In a video game that I'm playing called "*Oblivion*" I stumbled upon a village in which some kind of demon named Daedra set a fire to its resident's houses. One of them says:

"*Many people died but some got out alive*."

Does "*get out*" meaning escape (*because this is what I think it means here*) **can only be used when person who is escaping is located inside some kind of structure?** This definition suggests that it doesn't:

intransitive verb
1
: LEAVE, ESCAPE
*doubted that he would get out alive* (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: This stuff with get out and get off and get about etc. etc. are very tricky. Please do not downvote these questions.

Comment: In the video game did the fire occur at night or during the day. If night, it's likely the residents were at home when their village was set on fire, if this happened during the day time then some villagers could have been outside; farming, hunting, children playing etc. but you would still say **some got out (of a dangerous situation) alive**.

Comment: As your dictionary says "that he would get out alive," means the danger is over. That's all. Escape to safety, not always exit a space.

Comment: @Lambie You are very smart. It's obvious only to native speakers. This is the point of this forum I believe. Also, what is pretty annoying is that it doesn't really matter if the context is about people being in their houses at night. I want to know whether this phrase can additionary to it's literal meaning "to go outside" mean to "escape a situation of danger" (regardless whether the danger is inside or out in the open).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also: Many people died [in the fire or in the flood or in the disaster] but some got out alive. We say: in a fire or in a flood, yes, But with death, it's likely to be a fire or **some other natural disaster**.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it means you are inside a structure or vehicle or something else, a cave for example. I am only dealing here with physical things, not other ones.

- *He got out of the car* very quickly. [*exit the car* when in it]
- He got out of the cave by 2:00 pm.
  BUT: get off a plane or train for disembark from it

HOWEVER:
There was a huge fire.
**Two possibilities** with get out:

- Not everyone got out. [escaped, **got out alive is implied**]
- Not everyone got out alive.

*get out of the house*=to go and do something outside the house or as above.
Otherwise: *go out of the house*, to exit it.
**get out of a situation**=to remove oneself from it, not informal.

However, if it means get out of a situation, it would be: Not everyone got out **of it**. [i.e. the situation]

Comment: downvoters: tsk, tsk, tsk